# Would writing to full physical memory break the hardware?

Tags: assembly, x86, ram, firmware, uefi

I am playing around with UEFI and based on Specs after calling ExitBootServices i own all the memory. Are there any memory regions mapped by the CPU to some physical hardware ROMs that could be updated if I write to that memory address ?

For some "playing around" purposes I want to try to create a loop that goes over the full physical memory and writes 0 to all locations and I wonder if that could break the hardware, like suddenly overwriting the UEFI firmware or so. Or is it safe to use and all be back at normal after reboot.

Comment: There are some registers that are mapped to specific memory regions (ex. the HPET), the system may become unstable if you fill them with 0s, if this is possible without getting an exception.

Comment: you can technically damage hardware yes, more likely the peripherals will go down but recover on reboot assuming your code doesnt get run again.  Actually some may not reset, it depends on the implementation, possible a power cycle will be required...

Comment: if you are limiting yourself to exposed (d)ram and not all of the address space then sure go for it, avoiding your code, data, and stack.  Shouldnt hurt anything.

Comment: My goal is actually to try to go from 0x00 to the maximum physical address of RAM reported by UEFI.

Comment: It’s not correct that you own all of memory after calling ExitBootServices. In fact, UEFI requires that you call GetMemoryMap prior to calling ExitBootServices, and even requires that you **prove** that you’ve done so by passing the cookie from GetMemoryMap to ExitBootServices. ExitBootServices fails if you don’t pass the correct cookie. If you touch the reserved areas of memory in the memory map, your system behavior is undefined.